# What is the postgresql equivalent to ora_hash

Tags: database, postgresql, function, database-migration

Is there any equivalent function in postgresql database for ora_hash function in Oracle.

I already tried the MD5 function in postgresql but the value is not same as Oracle.

Comment: [`ora_hash`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions136.htm#SQLRF06313) does not define what hash algorithm it uses. Finding an equivalent would have to be by trial and error and could change from version to version. `ora_hash` produces a 32 bit digest, very small, so it's definitely not MD5 which is 128 bit.